# Fetching records based on batch size in apache beam

Tags: batch-processing, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have 100k records to be processed and I need to fetch 10k each time, process them and fetch another 10k until I process all the 100k records which I call as batch size to reduce the processing overhead each time by fetching all the records at once.

Any suggestions on how to achieve it using Apache beam

I am using spark runner.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do this with Beam as well.  My Sinks crash with OutOfMemoryException because they try to load everything at once.

Comment: I did it by processing the pipeline multiple times based on the batch size, due to the beam's parallel processing feature i was not able to achieve what i wanted to do, so i have implemented in another way. Your out of memory error is probably because the same iteration might be picked by all the threads at a time and processing the same based on your logic. I too have faced the problem initially